# Why does operator<< need const?

Tags: c++

Here's my code. This runs, but it gives me an error when I remove the const from ostream& operator<< . Why?

As a side question, the error message shown is: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&' . How does this indicate that I'm missing a const?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class pair_int{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    pair_int(int x, int y):x(x),y(y){};
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream & s, pair_int & c);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream & s, const pair_int & c){
    s << c.x;
    s << ",";
    s << c.y;
    return s;
}
pair_int square(int x){
    return pair_int(x, x*x);

}
int main(int argc,char * argv []){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << square(x);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Outputting an object should not change the objects content, thus the object being output is constant or `const`.

Comment: You couldn't pass temporary instances otherwise?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object

Comment: The *declaration* of `operator<<` must match its definition.  If you are going to remove `const`, you need to do this to both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the result of calling `square()` is an r-value, which can bind to a const l-value reference or an r-value reference, but not a mutable l-value reference.

This is by design, to prevent you from accidentally creating temporaries that you then mutate and throw away without meaning to.

(does not apply to rule-breaking Microsoft compilers)

Comment: Does it apply to other rule breaking compilers? :) :)

Comment: @RSahu I'm not aware of any other companies trying to hold back innovation by refusing to conform to internationally greed standards, but if you bring them to my attention I will happily call them out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of any other companies. I work with MS compilers on  a daily basis. The pain hits home for me.

Comment: @RSahu mingw and clang might be viable alternatives for you if you want a compiler that isn't a toy.

Comment: If you want to disable non-standard extensions with VC++, you can use `/Za`. And btw, clang and gcc also enable non-standard extensions by default.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley extensions yes. Blatant transgressions of the language, no.

Comment: What makes this a transgression, as opposed to an extension? Some people consider the rule a form of hand-holding that is not welcome in a low level language like C++, and so the relaxation of this rule is useful to them.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It prevents successful compilation in a standards-conforming compiler. It's therefore a bug. Furthermore, it allows developers to compile code with semantics that they probably did not intend. Mutating a temporary is almost always an indication of a logic error.

Comment: The extensions turned on by gcc and clang do the exact same thing (prevent successful compilation in standards conforming compilers). And to the second point, that's the hand holding I was talking about.

Comment: "Mutating a temporary is almost always an indication of a logic error" (repeated) - handholding someone while they make an error is evil.